# Linux kernel fails to assign memory to the PCIe device when the BAR size is set to 1GB

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

Linux kernel fails to assign memory to the device when the BAR size is set to 1GB. The device enumeration works fine as long as the BAR memory size is set to 512MB. But when set to 1GB, it enumerates the device, but then the memory mappings are not assigned.

> Control: I/O- Mem- BusMaster- SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr-
>   Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-  Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B-
>   ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- SERR- 
>   (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [disabled]  Region 2: Memory at
>    (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [disabled]  Region 4: Memory
>   at  (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [disabled]

What could be the reason for this? What can be done to debug this?

Enabled kernel debug at boot-up and this is what is logged for that device:

> [    7.087688] pci 0000:8b:00.0: BAR 4: can't assign mem (size
>   0x40000000) [    7.109427] pci 0000:8b:00.0: BAR 0: can't assign mem
>   (size 0x100000) [    7.130599] pci 0000:8b:00.0: BAR 2: can't assign
>   mem (size 0x2000)

Comment: Could be DMA memory fragmentation. Try loading the driver before other PCI drivers.

Comment: It seems kernel can't find continuous memory chunk of such length.

Answer (score 0):

you can try setpci -s "your pcie device bus number" COMMAND=0x02 for example setpcie -s 01:00.0 COMMAND=0x02 this will enable memory mapped transfers for your pcie device.

you can refer to this link:
https://forums.xilinx.com/t5/PCI-Express/lspci-reports-BAR-0-disabled/td-p/747139